# Hibernate query error with collection defined as Set

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, glassfish, entitymanager

This error is thrown from one of my jersey-glassfish rest endpoint ( from domain logs ):

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type specified for TypedQuery [com.tanukis.streetama.entity.Flow] is incompatible with query return type [interface java.util.Set]
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:458)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerWrapper.java:566)
>       at com.tanukis.streetama.dao.FluxManager.getBlacklist(FluxManager.java:571)

The query is defined in orm.xml :

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.blacklistedFlow FROM StreetamaUser s WHERE s.uid = :uid
```

Here is my StreetamaUser entity:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade= javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
    name="ws_user_blacklist",
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "blacklisted_flow_id", "user_id" }),
    joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name="user_id",referencedColumnName="uid")
    },
    inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name="blacklisted_flow_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    }
)
@XmlTransient
private Set<Flow> blacklistedFlow = new HashSet<Flow>();
```

And the query call:

```
List<Flow> result = em.createNamedQuery( "StreetamaUser.findBlacklist", Flow.class )
            .setParameter("iduser", uid )
            .setFirstResult(startitem)
            .setMaxResults(itemnbr)
            .getResultList();
```

I can't understand the Hibernate exception. getResultList return a list, so why it complains about the query return type ?

Comment: If you down-vote, please say why... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a java.Util.List instead of a Set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Hibernate doesn't like List (Bag semantic). As the list must not contains duplicate, set is meaningfull here... But yes, if there is no other solution, I may update my model and use a list

Answer (score 0):

You don't. It is always a `List` even if it doesn't contains duplicate values like set. I don't see why it matters in the first place.

Comment: I know that with **Jackson**, you can avoid type erasure with org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeReference. Any way to do something like that and avoid the hibernate exception ?